# Change rating numbers to 1 - 5

Tags: php, arrays, math, numbers

I have an array of rating numbers.

```
array(34, 35, 33, 17, 38, 29, 31, 23)
```

I want the numbers to automatically turn into a rating between 1 and 5 (1, 2, 3, 4 or 5).

**Example**

- "38" (highest number) should have a rating of 5
- "17" (lowest number) should have a rating of 1.
- "31" should probably have a rating of 3.

How do I calculate this with PHP code? The highest number might be higher than 35 and the lowest might be lower than 17.

Comment: So the highest number is always 5, and the lowest is 1. Fine, but what about the rest? Could they be also 1 or 5, or only between 2 and 4?

Comment: @NorthBridge I updated the question. The ratings can be 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to map the numbers **17 and 38** to the numbers **1 and 5**, interpolating all values in between. Let us use these numbers in the below example where **num** represents any number from the range:

```
(num - 17)                  maps 17 and 38 to 0 and 21
(num - 17) / (21)           maps  0 and 21 to 0 and  1
(num - 17) / (21) * (4)     maps  0 and  1 to 0 and  4
(num - 17) / (21) * (4) + 1 maps  0 and  4 to 1 and  5
```

PHP Code:

```
function mapvaluetorange($array, $a, $b) {
    $map = array();
    $min = min($array);
    $max = max($array);
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $map[] = array(
            "old" => $value,
            "new" => ($value - $min) / ($max - $min) * ($b - $a) + $a
        );
    }
    return $map;
}
$map = mapvaluetorange(array(34, 35, 33, 17, 38, 29, 31, 23), 1, 5);
```

Output:

```
int(34) -> float(4.2380952380952)
int(35) -> float(4.4285714285714)
int(33) -> float(4.047619047619)
int(17) -> int(1)
int(38) -> int(5)
int(29) -> float(3.2857142857143)
int(31) -> float(3.6666666666667)
int(23) -> float(2.1428571428571)
```

Use the `round` function to round floats to integers.

Comment: I'd make that a function and add in `round()` so you get a whole number as the result.

Comment: round() is probably the most correct way to round the ratings.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate approach, you could use an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and `array_map()` to map the values of the array to the range you want like this:

```
    <?php
    $x = array(34, 35, 33, 17, 38, 29, 31, 23);
    $max = max($x);
    $min = min($x);
    $map = function($value) use($min,$max) {return (int)round((($value-$min)/($max-$min))*4+1);};
    $x = array_map($map, $x);
    var_dump($x);
```

Gives:

```
    array(8) {
        [0] =>   int(4)
        [1] =>   int(4)
        [2] =>   int(4)
        [3] =>   int(1)
        [4] =>   int(5)
        [5] =>   int(3)
        [6] =>   int(4)
        [7] =>   int(2)
    }
```